# How to intercept a request in Jersey using Annotations?

Tags: java, rest, annotations, jersey, intercept

I'm using Jersey to build a REST API with your standard annotation based routing.

My question is, how can I use a "custom annotation" (in this case @InternalOnly) to intercept a request and run code ***before*** the request hits the resource and the ***// DO STUFF*** block is executed?

```
@Path("app")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public final class SomeResource {

    @GET
    @Path("something")
    @InternalOnly
    public Response getSomething() {

        // DO STUFF
    }
}
```

I would then have another class that would handle the **@InternalOnly** header...

```
public final class InternalOnlyHandler implements SomethingProbably {

    public void handle(Object someContext) {

        // HANDLE INTERNAL ONLY AUTHENTICATION
    }
}
```

My purpose is basically I need certain API resources to be available internally ONLY and others publicly available and the Authentication is slightly different for both so registering a simple *ContainerRequestFilter* won't do the job.

I can't figure this out -- please help!

Comment: You should check this out, it will probably help: http://blog.dejavu.sk/2015/01/21/intercepting-jersey-resource-method-calls/

Comment: Thanks, I already figured it out. Did it using a ContainerRequestFilter and then checking for certain annotations WITHIN that filter and routing the request to sub-handlers. I would've posted the answer to my own question but I'm just too busy. Thanks though, that page would've also helped :)

Comment: If anyone ever needs help with this just message me and I'll be happy to post my solution.